# Ошибка OSError 40 при передачи данных на сервер micropython библиотека urequests

Tags: python, http, https, esp8266, micropython

Подскажите пожалуйста,отправляю данные на сервер, если передаю url = **http**://dfdfgfh.ru все работает отлично, если url = **https**://dfdfgfh.ru ошибка OSError 40 , как с этим бороться?

```
from machine import Pin
import dht
from urequests import post, get
import json


def dth11_data(url, token):
    sensor = dht.DHT11(Pin(14))
    sensor.measure()
    d = {
        "temperature": sensor.temperature(),
        "humidity": sensor.humidity()
    }
    data = json.dumps(d)
    response = post(url, data=data, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                  'Authorization': token})
```

спасибо

Comment: https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/issues/400

Comment: Получается решения нет еще?